# MySQL Stored Proc to Calculate Payroll Report

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am having some trouble coming up with a stored proc in MySQL to calculate the payroll report.

The database looks like the following

```
**Employee**
EmployeeID
....
....

**Timesheet**
TimesheetID
EmployeeID
....

**TimesheetDetails**
TimesheetDetailID
TimesheetID
ProjectID
WorkDate
Hours

**EmployeePayRate**
EmployeeID
Rate
StartDate
```

The pay periods are two weeks, the problem is the pay rate could change multiple times during the pay period.

This is the query stored proc I have thus far.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `sp_report_payroll`(IN p_startDate VARCHAR(15), IN p_endDate VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN

    SELECT
        e.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
        CONCAT(e.LastName, ', ', e.FirstName) AS Resource,
        (SELECT rt.Description FROM Roles rt WHERE rt.RoleId = e.RoleId) as Role,
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(td.BillableHours)
            FROM
                Timesheets t,
                TimesheetDetails td,
                Projects p
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
            AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
            AND p.ProjectID NOT IN (24,29,34,606,614,746)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE(p_startDate)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE(p_endDate)
        ) AS RegularHours,
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(td.BillableHours)
            FROM
                Timesheets t,
                TimesheetDetails td,
                Projects p
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
            AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
            AND (p.ProjectID = 29 OR p.ProjectID = 614)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE(p_startDate)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE(p_endDate)
        ) AS PTO,
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(td.BillableHours)
            FROM
                Timesheets t,
                TimesheetDetails td,
                Projects p
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
            AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
            AND p.ProjectID = 24
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE(p_startDate)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE(p_endDate)
        ) AS Holiday,
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(td.BillableHours)
            FROM
                Timesheets t,
                TimesheetDetails td,
                Projects p
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
            AND p.ProjectID = td.ProjectID
            AND p.ProjectID = 746
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE(p_startDate)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE(p_endDate)
        ) AS FloatingHoliday,
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(td.BillableHours)
            FROM
                Timesheets t,
                TimesheetDetails td
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
            AND td.ProjectID NOT IN (34,606)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE(p_startDate)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE(p_endDate)
        ) AS Total,
        (
            SELECT 
                epr.Rate 
            FROM 
                EmployeePayRate epr ,
                Timesheets t,
                TimesheetDetails td
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
            AND epr.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE(p_startDate)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE(p_endDate)
            AND epr.StartDate <= td.WorkDate
            ORDER BY epr.StartDate DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS PayRate,
        (
            SELECT
            (SELECT 
                epr.Rate 
            FROM 
                EmployeePayRate epr ,
                Timesheets t,
                TimesheetDetails td
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
            AND epr.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE(p_startDate)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE(p_endDate)
            AND epr.StartDate <= td.WorkDate
            ORDER BY epr.StartDate DESC
            LIMIT 1)

            *

            (SELECT
                SUM(td.BillableHours)
            FROM
                Timesheets t,
                TimesheetDetails td
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
            AND t.TimeCardID = td.TimeCardID
            AND td.ProjectID NOT IN (34,606)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) >= DATE(p_startDate)
            AND DATE(td.WorkDate) <= DATE(p_endDate))
        ) AS GrossEarnings
    FROM
        Employee e
    WHERE (e.EmployeeID IN (SELECT t.EmployeeID 
        FROM TimesheetDetails tsd, Timesheets t 
        WHERE tsd.BillableHours > 0 
        AND tsd.WorkDate BETWEEN p_startDate AND p_endDate
        AND tsd.TimeCardID = t.TimeCardID
        ) OR e.Status = 'Active')
    AND (e.ResourceTypeID = 2 OR e.ResourceTypeID = 4)
    GROUP BY Resource
    ORDER BY Role, Resource ASC;

END
```

However this does not account for changing pay rates during a pay period. Can anyone provide the best way of handling this situation. Would it be cleaner to break some of these subqueries into functions?

UPDATE:

The report should show the following columns:

EmployeeID
Employee Name (LastName, FirstName)
Role
Regular Hours
PTO Hours
Holiday Hours
Floating Holiday Hours
Total Hours
Gross Earnings

As requested I have provided data but the attachment is to big for stackoverflow. The link is here for the mysql dump. I dropped it into the public folder of my OneDrive.

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=4D42EF88BE1FD96C&id=4D42EF88BE1FD96C%215903

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: I added the mysql dump of the relevant tables